# ReactJS - toggle a class with an onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an a tag that has an onclick function:

```
onClick={addActive.bind(this)}
```

My function needs to toggle a class on/off

```
function addActive(e){
alert("working");
e.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

I need to either figure out how to get this to work, OR how to make it work with some reactJS in my function.

When clicked the alert works properly, but the toggle doesn't.

Any insight would be appreciated. I am very new to reactJS.

The portion I am uncertain of is the `e.classList.toggle` part to identify the correct element.

Comment: Edited. It was the target....let me know if I need to better phrase this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your current code: `e` is an event, `e.target` is the element.

---

The reactish way would be to keep a boolean in the state, update that `onClick` and reflect the state to the elements class. First of all you need a boolean in state, e.g.:

```
 state = { isActive: false };
```

Then later on in the `render()` use it as:

```
 const { isActive } = state;

return (
 //...
 <div className={isActive ? active : ""} onClick={() => this.setState({ isActive: !isActive })} >Click me</div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. The e.target was what I was missing.